# Sunshine app runtime exception binary xml

Tags: java, android, xml

I am following the Udacity videos for creating the android sunshine app. After completing the first section I'm getting the following exception in logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.agent47.sunshine.app, PID: 3767
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.agent47.sunshine.app/com.example.agent47.sunshine.app.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:742)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:362)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                      at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:615)
                      at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:593)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2302)
                      at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:98)
                      at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5884)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:777)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:414)
                      at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2414)
                      at com.example.agent47.sunshine.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

The following is my code:

MainActivity.xml

```
package com.example.agent47.sunshine.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        PlaceholderFragment placeholde=new PlaceholderFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, placeholde);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

}
```

PlaceholderFragment.java

```
package com.example.agent47.sunshine.app;

import android.app.Fragment;
//import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * Created by Agent47 on 10/13/16.
 */

public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        String[] forecastArray={
            "Today - Sunny - 88/63",
            "Tomorrow - Foggy - 70/40",
                "Weds - Cloudy - 72/63",
                "Thurs - Asteroids - 75/65",
                "Fri - Heavy Rain - 65/56",
                "Sat - HELP TRAPPED IN WEATHERSTATION - 60/51",
                "Sun - Sunny -80/68"
        };

        List<String> weekForecast=new ArrayList<String>(
                Arrays.asList(forecastArray)
        );

        mForecastAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.listitem,
                R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
                weekForecast);

        View rootview= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        ListView listView=(ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

        return rootview;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.agent47.sunshine.app.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_main" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragmen"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_forecast"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

listitem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_forecast">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Today - Sunny - 88/63"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/list_item_forecast_textview"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

androidmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.agent47.sunshine.app">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the below things to remove error:

1. Remove **fragment tag** from activity_main.xml
2. In MainActivity.class change below line

   ```
   fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, placeholde);
   ```

to

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.activity_main, placeholde);
```

Comment: Sorry its working. I missed the first point removing the fragment tag.

By removing the fragment tag is it still considered as using of fragments in the app?

Comment: Yes, using Fragment means creating classes which extends from "Fragment". It doesn't mean including fragment tag in layout

Answer (score 0):

Try replace in Activity and Fragment:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

with:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

and set:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

Comment: How is this supposed to fix the problem with the NullPointerException?

Comment: Error:(24, 59) error: incompatible types: PlaceholderFragment cannot be converted to Fragment

Comment: I have tried that but I get this error:

Error:(24, 59) error: incompatible types: PlaceholderFragment cannot be converted to Fragment

Comment: Use getSupportFragmentManager() instead getFragmentManager. If still not working inside your Activity xml replace fragment with FrameLayout